# Fail to run rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot run my rails server. I used rails on windows 64 bit. When i run

```
rails server
```

I get the following results:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2.rb
:8:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/RailsInstaller
/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.15/mysql2
/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/
lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from C:/Users/azlan187/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I absolutely don't know how to fix this. Any help would be really appreciated!

ps: please tell me if i need to provide more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64-bit system? The first line of your error output complains about mysql.so not being a valid Win32 application. I would start investigating on that, and if it does not yield anything, try googling for "mysql gem errors". I personally had a lot of problems getting the mysql gem to work on windows, andfrom my past experience, usually it is a matter of sourcing the correct libmysql file.

Comment: I used 64bit windows. I have problems with installing the mysql ruby gems. I tried installing using the 64bit Connector/C but fails. Then, I installed mysql ruby gem using the 32bit Connector/C and it works.I don't understand why since I'm using 64bit windows. I think this is related to why my rails server fail to run. But I don't know if I have to re-install mysql ruby gems.